# Disable automatic publishing on Google Play

Tags: android, validation, google-play, publish

I'm going to publish an App on the Google Play Store. 
I know that the validation can take up to 48h more or less.
I would like to know if there is a way to submit the App for validation, and then when it's validated, tu publish it by my self, clicking on a button "PUBLISH" or something.
Apple propound two ways of publishing process:
- Automatic: just right after the validation, the App is automatically published.
- Manual: after the validation process, we get a notification saying that the App is ready to publish. By clicking on a button whenever I want and publish the App.
Is there a "Manual" way on Android ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not a programming question. http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'delayed publication' mode in your Play console - look for dropdown in upper right screen corner.